# 404 Errors using Vert.x web proxy code taken from its documentation

Tags: webserver, reverse-proxy, vert.x

I am using the Vert.x Web library to create a test application for a reverse proxy. I am using the information provided on the Vert.x site:

https://vertx.io/docs/4.1.0/vertx-web-proxy/java/#_using_vert_x_web_proxy

I have written some simple test code, based on the documentation at the above site:

```
public class WebTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
  
       HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();

       HttpProxy proxy = HttpProxy.reverseProxy(client);
       proxy.origin(8080,"localhost");
  
       HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
       Router router = Router.router(vertx);
  
       router.route(HttpMethod.GET,"/foo").handler(ProxyHandler.create(proxy));

       server.requestHandler(router);
       server.listen(8010);
    }
}
```

I have a web server (the so- called "origin" in Vert.x terminology) running on Port 8080. The only difference between the code above and the code on the web site is that I am using different port numbers for the proxy and the origin server. According to the documentation on the Vert.x website, a browser going to http://localhost:8010/foo should access the origin server.

Instead, I am getting 404 Not found errors.

Is there something missing in this code? Maybe something not covered in the documentation?

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

@Factor Three you are missing backend part of the guide and also you are mixing parts in an unorganized way. Following the guide it can be like this:

```
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    // Origin Server (Backend 8080)---------
    // Here you deploy the real server with the endpoint ("hello world" in this case)
    HttpServer backendServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

    Router backendRouter = Router.router(vertx);

    backendRouter
        .route(HttpMethod.GET, "/foo")
        .handler(
            rc -> {
              rc.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/plain").end("hello world");
            });

    backendServer.requestHandler(backendRouter).listen(8080);

    // Proxy Server (8010)
    // Here you deploy the server that will act as a proxy

    HttpServer proxyServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

    Router proxyRouter = Router.router(vertx);

    proxyServer.requestHandler(proxyRouter);

    proxyServer.listen(8010);

    // Proxy Magic
    // Here you route proxy server requests (8010) to the origin server (8080)

    HttpClient proxyClient = vertx.createHttpClient();

    HttpProxy httpProxy = HttpProxy.reverseProxy(proxyClient);
    httpProxy.origin(8080, "localhost");

    proxyRouter.route(HttpMethod.GET, "/foo").handler(ProxyHandler.create(httpProxy));
```

Comment: Actuallly, I am not missing anything. As stated in my original post, I have an origin server that is listening on port 8080. FYI: this is a separate "backend" server implemented using Spring Boot which serves (among other things) web pages. I did not bother to include its code because (1) there is a good deal of it whose details would detract from the discussion and (2) it is irrelevant to the probem described here. It is a server listening on localhost:8080. The proxy code returns 404 errors when you attempt to access it. That it is not implemented using vert.x is irrelevant.

Comment: BTW: before anyone asks, my Spring Boot based origin server is accessible when accessed directly. When going directly to it using localhost:8080 I get the index page without problems. It is only the vert.x web proxy (localhost:8010) that returns 404 errors.